# Show DIV with AJAX in PHP After Saving Data to Mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, html

I Have a problem here. I try to show up the information box using DIV after successfully save the data to mysql.

Here my short code.

// Mysql insertion process

```
if($result){?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {  
        $.ajax({
        $('#info').fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000)
        $('#infomsg').html('Success.')
            });
    }
    </script>
<?php }
```

How can DIV appear? I tried but nothing comes up. Any help? Thank you

Comment: $.ajax isn't used that way. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this script?

Comment: why are you using $.ajax ??

Comment: I have php script file, let's say index.php that user can sign up from there. I use ajax to save data using register.php, so after user register i want to show DIV for information that register "success" In register.php that contain script save POST data to mysql and in result "$result" i want show DIV that i said before..

Answer (score 0):

a basic jQuery ajax request:

```
$(function() {  
    $.ajax({
        url: "the url you want to send your request to",
        success: function() {
            //something you want to do upon success
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your answer. I have use that function for saving POST data to mysql. So what i want know is showing confirmation box "SUCCESS" using DIV from another file. User can register in INDEX.PHP and saving post data use ajax with URL:register.php and after success saving data to mysql i want let user know that register success using DIV.

Comment: as you said you have done the database part, the only thing left is to show you DIV then. what you need to do is put your code in the success function and show your DIV, simple jQuery functions like fadeIn(), show(), css() can all achieve what you want. I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. My answer is just providing a standard way to use ajax

Comment: if i try use your answer, what i should put in URL?

Here my short code from ajax that call register.php

$(function() {  
  $(".register").click(function() {  
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax_register.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
 
        success: function () {
          $('.register').attr("disabled", false);
          $('#LoadingRegister').fadeOut(400);
          $("#username").focus();
        }
  });
  return false;
  }
  });  
});

Comment: the url which handles your database request. in your case i guess should be register.php(if you are inserting things into database via this page)

Comment: I only need in ajax-register.php is call function to show Confirmation Box using DIV so user can know if their registration success.

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you are talking about. you can break things like this, leave the success function empty and try your ajax request to see if you have successfully inserted data. if it works, the only thing left is to show your div in the success function

Comment: in ajax-register.php that mysql insert code. in register.php that just ajax code call ajax-register.php in URL:

Comment: I guess i know what your problem is, you can insert data, but you can't show things upon success, because you are not querying the database via ajax, you are actually querying database using the form submission. If you want to do it via ajax, you should put onsubmit="return false" as an attribute of your form, than use you jquery ajax to submit your form, use the javascript code you have done.

Comment: i already do this  onsubmit="return false" and nothing wrong with submission from form to mysql. The problem is, i want show DIV with message "SUCCESS" after saving data to mysql. Showing DIV with fadein only can be done by jquery (maybe). So i don't know how to call jquery function in PHP script below if($result){

Comment: so there is nothing to do with php, ajax the only thing you should be doing is put $('#LoadingRegister').fadeOut(400) in your success function

Comment: wont show up, i try like you said. even <script>alert("SUCCESS");</script> wont show up

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a session of ID and you want to retrieve it in your database.

here is: info.php

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id"><input>
 <input type="submit" onclick="showResult(id)" value="Click to Show Result"></input>
 function showResult(id){
 $j.ajax(
      method:"POST",
      url:"example.php",
      data: {userid:id},
      sucess: function(success){
    $('#infomsg').html(Success)
        });
  }
  <div id= "infomsg"></div>
```

example.php

```
$id = $_POST['userid']; ///////from the data:{userid :id}

//////////config of your db
$sql = mysql_query("select * from users where id = $id");
foreach ($sql as $sq){
echo $sq['id']."<br>";
}
```

the "infomsg" will get the result from the function success and put it in the div.

Comment: can you give me example for this data: info(variable use to method POST):(inside variable of the div info),? thank you

Comment: I will try it. I will leave comment later. Thank's. But seems will work.

Comment: First think. #infomsg should be hide(). After success query at example.php. How can i make #infomsg show up?

Comment: it will always hidden until you click the button. because the div has no data and style. but if you want to hide it first <div id= "infomsg" style="display:none"></div>

Comment: How if data:$('form').serialize() ?? can i use it? because i have a lot textbox to entry. If can use data:$('form').serialize() how can i use in example.php? thank's

Comment: I mean, how do i call in example.php? because i use this     $(function() {  
      $(".register").click(function() {  
If there anything wrong? Can you help me to fix it? thank you

Comment: there is a lot textbox for registration form. But if you looking about button submit code here is                  <button class="register" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" style="width: 84px; height: 70px">Sign Up</button>

Comment: and form code is     <form class="myform" action="#" method="POST" name="myform" style="width: 300px; text-align: left; height:190px" id="myform">

Comment: i think you need to use html to php only. instead of ajax.

Comment: do you have a sample?

Comment: i still not understand. Even i use simple script like <script> alert("HELLO");</script> still wont show up.

Comment: hmm did you pup the <script> inside your <?php tag?